# SpringBoot application connected with mysql database giving connection error

Tags: mysql

As when i am running application using eclipse ide it runs and as well as connects to database
but when i build project using maven and run the jar file from command prompt it shows that last packet was received 0 miliseconds ago
I have tried to add validate query, idle timeout, autoreconnect,testonBorrow, connection timeout, uninstalled mysql and reinstall it , changed db and also configure build path again but always it is running in eclipse but shows same error in command prompt for running or building the jar

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure


The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:338)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:777)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:486)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1340)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:316)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:329)
        ... 40 more
```

It further goes on

Comment: Could you post some logging? And could you tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: i have restarted mysql service as well as changed jdbc url to 127.0.0.1 also added bind-address to my.ini file of mysql all works in eclipse but none of them changed the error for running jar file or building the jar file through command file. I can only build jar file  through eclipse and when i run mvn package same error is shown.

Comment: Can you add your code snippet?

Comment: ```management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled=true 


spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/demo
spring.datasource.username=newuser
spring.datasource.password=password ```

Comment: i see 2 possibilites: 1- eclipse using a different profile than the one used in maven.
2- try mvn clean before building again

Comment: how shall i use the same profile as eclipse for maven, and i also tried mvn clean but after clean also it  gives same  error

Comment: @RicardovanLaarhoven can u check i have added logs

Comment: @GurkiranKaur hey please check i have added

Comment: @sudarshan you have just added logs, please add code snippet of how you are creating connection and related classes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai check if this helps

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
skip-name-resolve=1
```

to my.ini(mysql) file and the issue has been resolved